# How to use the filename from the function outside it in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a program that takes the filedialog filename and then puts it into another function that is working with openpyxl, however the problem i am facing is that i can't access the filename outside of the function. I have also tried using return but to no avail. Please have a look at my code:

```
    file_path = ''
def file1():
   
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Excel Files",
                                                        "*.xlsx*"),
                                                       ("Excel",
                                                        "*.xls*")))
    
    file_path = filename
```

Comment: By default, `file_path` is a local variable inside the function.  Put `global file_path` at the top of the function to make it use the global variable.

Comment: While globals are frowned upon in general, everyone uses them from time to time. Another way along this line is to use a dictionary. Add `mydict=({"file_path":""})` in place of the original file_path. In the def use `mydict["file_path"]= filename` to update the dictionary. Then call elsewhere by using `mydict["file_path"]`. This has a small fringe debug benefit as you can do a quick `print(mydict)` to check this or any other keys you add are correct without having to call each one individually.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you sorted, variable assignment in def's can be annoying at times. Rather than trying to assign the variable twice, use a `return` to send the def results back out the def.

**Basic version:**

```
from tkinter import filedialog

def file1():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Excel Files",
                                                        "*.xlsx*"),
                                                       ("Excel",
                                                        "*.xls*")))
    return filename
 
file_path = file1()
print (file_path)
```

**Pathlib version:**

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from pathlib import Path


def file1():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Excel Files",
                                                        "*.xlsx*"),
                                                       ("Excel",
                                                        "*.xls*")))
    return filename
 
file_path = Path(file1())
print (file_path)
```

**Minimal working TK example:**

This will make a small window with a button, click the button and select your file, the file name will appear underneath the button. The secret sauce for TK in using the `lambda` function, with that you can treat TK `command=` pretty much like a regular line in a python script.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pathlib import Path

def file1():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",
                                          title = "Select a File",
                                          filetypes = (("Excel Files",
                                                        "*.xlsx*"),
                                                       ("Excel",
                                                        "*.xls*")))
    return filename
    
def makelabel(text):
   tk.Label(text=text).pack()    
 
window = tk.Tk() 
title = tk.Label(text="File Dialog Test").pack()
button = tk.Button(text="Open File",command= lambda:makelabel(file1())).pack()
window.mainloop()
```

All these examples will open a file dialog and return the selected filename e.g. `R:\foo.xls`. The only difference is [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is handy if you wish to break the filename down into various parts easily.

For future questions it's better to include a more complete minimum working/non working example with any required imports.

Comment: OP has already said *"I have also tried using return but to no avail"*.  Also the function may be triggered by a button, so return the value does not help.

Comment: We have no way of knowing what OP is trying to do outside of the context of the presented code snippet. In this respect I have answered their initial question. If OP expands upon their details I or another can adjust the answer to help further.

When I started with python, I could not get my head around `return` at first, it could be they simply did not use it correctly. Again expansion/clarification of the question will help us understand better.

Comment: I've added a minimal TK example now showing how to call the filedialog from a button and return it to a new label. This will allow OP to hopefully achieve their desired goal